# Anaconda will not recognizing the "area" library?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, area

This is my first time using Anaconda so I hope this is just some silly mistake but I've been looking for a long time and can't find anything specific to this library. (https://pypi.org/project/area/)

So I tried to run my flask app:
[image]

And there is no module named area. So I tried to `pip3 install area`:
[image]

It seems to have worked, but when I run I get the same error.

I then tried to `conda install area` and that also failed:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Simply try pip install area and let me know if it works

Comment: I mentioned that I did that in the post @aryashah2k